# Only first item is clickable ListView onItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a ListView with some items in it, on a specific item click, I want to run code which needs the index of the item. However, only the first item is clickable and is getting recogniced, I was wondering if my problem is in my CustomAdapter but since i have never done something like this before I have no clue about that. Thanks for the help in advance.

Here's my CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapterGroups extends ArrayAdapter<ModelGroups>{

private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<ModelGroups> modelsArrayList;

public CustomAdapterGroups(Context context, ArrayList<ModelGroups> modelsArrayList)
{
    super(context, R.layout.target_item, modelsArrayList);

    this.context = context;
    this.modelsArrayList = modelsArrayList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // Inflater creation
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // get rowView from inflater
    View rowView = null;
    if (!modelsArrayList.get(position).isGroupHeader())
    {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.target_item, parent, false);

        // get icon, title & counter views from the rotView
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon_idea);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_title_group);
        Button colorView = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_color_group);
        //TextView counterView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_counter);

        // set text for textview
        imgView.setImageResource(modelsArrayList.get(position).getIcon());
        titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        colorView.setBackgroundColor(modelsArrayList.get(position).getColor());
        //counterView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getCounter());

    }
    else
    {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header_item, parent, false);
        TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_header);
        titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    return rowView;
}

}
```

On my fragment (I am using a tabbed layout) which contains the ListView I created an onItemClickListener but this one is empty except of one Log.e("", position);

I just wonder what I am missing to achieve to get the position of all clicked items properly.

EDIT: @Brian, this is my fragment, I create the ListView items in generateData according to a list of objects I get.

```
public class dashboardtab_main extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

ImageButton create_group;
Switch change_mode;
ListView list_groups;
List<Group> userGroups;
PacketBuilder pb = new PacketBuilder();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dashboardtab_main, container, false);

    userGroups = new ArrayList<Group>();
    userGroups = pb.getUserGroups();

    create_group = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_createGroup);
    change_mode = (Switch) rootView.findViewById(R.id.switch_mode);
    list_groups = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_groups);

    create_group.setOnClickListener(this);
    change_mode.setOnClickListener(this);
    //list_groups.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    CustomAdapterGroups adapter = new CustomAdapterGroups(getActivity(), generateData());

    list_groups.setAdapter(adapter);

    list_groups.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String item = list_groups.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Log.e("Dashboard", item);
        }
    });

    return rootView;



}


private ArrayList<ModelGroups> generateData()
{
    ArrayList<ModelGroups> modelGroupes = new ArrayList<ModelGroups>();
    modelGroupes.add(new ModelGroups("Groups"));

    //for (:) {}
    for(int i=0; i < userGroups.size(); i++) {
        modelGroupes.add(new ModelGroups(R.drawable.avatar_circle_blue_120dp, userGroups.get(i).getName(), Color.parseColor(userGroups.get(i).getColor())));
    }
    return modelGroupes;
}
```

Comment: This `CustomAdapter` code looks pretty good to me as it is. Can you perhaps share the `ListView` code or how you're using your `CustomAdapter` in your Fragment? By the way, just for style and organization, you should probably create a local variable for your `ModelGroups` to store a pointer to `modelsArrayList.get(position)` rather than using `modelsArrayList.get(position)` every time. Hope that makes it a little cleaner!

Comment: added the code to my question and i will add a local variable to make it look more clean!

Comment: Hmm this still looks pretty good to me. And you say you can see the entire list but only the first item is clickable? I don't know if this will fix anything, but try using `adapter.getItem(position)` instead of `list_groups.getItemAtPosition(position)`. Can you perhaps share the entire `CustomAdapter` code including the initialization?

Comment: How do you mean the entire CustomAdapter? The first code block is my CustomAdapter im using and in the second block im creating a new instance of this one to use it for the ListView. Changing the code to adapter.getItem(position) didn't help, it still does only output the position when pressing the first item.

Comment: Apologies for my late response, did you fix this? If not, I'm looking through the `CustomAdapter` and Fragment code and it looks fine with me so far. I notice you're trying use some mixed types with the `getView` where you have group items and group headers. Have you tried making them all the same type just to see if you can isolate the problem?

Comment: Everythings good, I fixed it, I still don't know what was wrong but i rewrote the whole CustomAdapter and now it is working again, very strange. Thank you for your help :)